# Rendering Knockout value using jQuery's append

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to render Knockout in jQuery `append` but it seems that the value fails to render. I need help on rendering the `div` as shown in the html into the jQuery append container.

```js
var employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName": "Jones"}
];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.LoadMore = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.OnLoadMoreClick = function() { 
  $.ajax({
    $.each(employees, function(index,value) {
       self.LoadMore.push(value);
    });
  
    $.each(employees, function(index,value) {
       var container = '';
       $('#LoadMoreContainer').append(container);
    });
  });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="LoadMoreContainer">
  <!-- How to move this part into jquery append?
  <!-- ko forEach: LoadMore -->
  <div><div data-bind="firstName"></div><div data-bind="lastName"></div></div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<div data-bind="click: OnLoadMoreClick">Load More</div>
```

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26842/ . let us know

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do this!** Don't append DOM elements yourself.

Knockout is an MVVM framework, which keeps the View (= DOM) in synch with your view models for you. It *wants* to be in control of the DOM. If you use Knockout, try to use as little jQuery as possible. Avoid it almost completely for any DOM manipulation, except when it is really warrented (e.g. the docs say it's okay).

(Typical exceptions would include, you only manipulate DOM yourself in [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) (which are meant explicitly for that), in [pre- or post-rendering of `foreach` bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements), or occasionaly in [the `event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html).)

But again, if you can help it: **don't do this**!

Instead, add items to the `observableArray`, and let *Knockout* update your view model accordingly:

```js
var employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName": "Jones"}
];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.LoadMore = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.OnLoadMoreClick = function() { 
    $.each(employees, function(index, value) {
      self.LoadMore.push(value);
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="LoadMoreContainer">
  <!-- ko foreach: LoadMore -->
  <div><span data-bind="text: firstName"></span> <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span></div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<button data-bind="click: OnLoadMoreClick">Load More</button>
```